# OpenGL primitives too dark when multitexturing?

Tags: opengl, rendering, primitive, multitexturing

I'm having a problem getting accurate primitive colours when I'm using multi-texturing elsewhere in the scene. Basically, I have some lines and polygons that I am trying render over a video texture (I'm using 3 stage multitexturing to create the video texture)... Anyhow, I know the problem is not alpha related... In fact, I know that in my texture update function if I just comment out the calls to glBindTexture() for texture levels 1 and 2, the primitive color is fine (so leaving texture level 0)... Is it trying to multitexture the primitives too (even though I'm obviously not setting texture coordinates for primitives)?

Comment: A screenshot would go a long way...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to disable multitexturing when not using it. OpenGL uses a state machine, so if you turn on a texture it will stay on until you explicitly turn it off.

Just because you're not setting coordinates, doesn't mean OpenGL will assume you're not using the texture.

Comment: How do you disable multitexturing?

Comment: How do you enable it? I'm not trying to be snarky, but usually extensions are enabled with a glEnable(...) call. Disabling it should just be glDisable(...) with the same parameter.